# How to use the data passed in ejs twice

Tags: node.js, ejs

I'm doing a project with node js and i need to display some data that i fetched from my database in an ejs file. The second time I try to display the data it is empty (the datalist I'm working with has empty fields). How can i do it?

The part of my ejs file where i use the data more than once:

```
<body>
<%- include('../partials/navbarHorizontal.ejs') %>

<div class="container justify-content-center my-4">
  <div class="row shadow-sm my-4">
    <div class="col m-4">
      <form action="/dekanat" method="POST">
        <div>Përditësoni dekanatin</div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="row">
            <label class="small gray" for="dekan">Dekani</label>
            <div>
              <input list="dekan_list" name="dekan" id="dekan" class="inputText"/>
              <datalist id="dekan_list">

              //The first time i use the data

                <%pedagoge.forEach(element => {%>
                <option
                  value="<%=element.emer_ped%> <%=element.mbiemer_ped%>"
                  data-id="<%=element.id_ped%>"
                ></option>
                <%});%>
              </datalist>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <label class="small gray" for="zvDek1">Zv. Dekani</label>
            <div>
              <input list="zvDek1_list" name="zvDek1" id="zvDek1" class="inputText" />
              <datalist id="zvDek1_list">

              //The second time i use the data

                <% pedagoge.forEach(element =>{%>
                <option
                  value="<%element.emer_ped%> <%element.mbiemer_ped%>"
                  data-id="<%element.id_ped%>"
                ></option>
                <%});%>
              </datalist>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col">
            <label class="small gray" for="zvDek2">Zv. Dekani</label>
            <div>
              <input list="zvDek2_list" name="zvDek2" id="zvDek2" class="inputText"/>

              <datalist id="zvDek2_list">

              //The third time i use the data

                <% pedagoge.forEach(element =>{%>
                <option
                  value="<%element.emer_ped%> <%element.mbiemer_ped%>"
                  data-id="<%element.id_ped%>"
                ></option>
                <%});%>
              </datalist>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mt-3 text-center">
          <div class="col-4">
            <input type="submit" value="Ruaj" class="rounded-pill buton" id="saveDek" />
          </div>

          <div class="col-4">
            <input type="reset" value="Fshi" class="rounded-pill buton" id="fshi"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The file where i render it is:

```
module.exports = {
dashboard: (req, res) => {
    alumniModel.display((resultAlumni) => {
      certificateModel.display((resultCertificate) => {
        docentModel.all((resultAllDocents) => {
          docentModel.notInDepartment((resultNotDep) => {
            departamentModel.all((resultDep) => {
              res.render("dashboard/dashboard.ejs", {
                eksperienca: resultAlumni,
                vertetime: resultCertificate,
                pedagoge: resultAllDocents,
                jashtem: resultNotDep,
                departament: resultDep,
              });
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  },
```

I know it is very nestled but i am new to to node js and i didnt know how to do it differenty.

The html code generated:

```
<div class="row shadow-sm my-4">
        <div class="col m-4">
          <form action="/dekanat" method="POST">
            <div>Përditësoni dekanatin</div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="row">
                <label class="small gray" for="dekan">Dekani</label>
                <div>
                  <input list="dekan_list" name="dekan" id="dekan" class="inputText"/>

                  //The first time 
                  <datalist id="dekan_list">
                    <option value="John Doe" data-id="1" ></option>
                    <option value="John Doe2" data-id="2" ></option>
                  </datalist>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <label class="small gray" for="zvDek1">Zv. Dekani</label>
                <div>
                  <input list="zvDek1_list" name="zvDek1" id="zvDek1" class="inputText" />

                  //The second time 
                  <datalist id="zvDek1_list"> 
                    <option value=" " data-id="" ></option> 
                    <option value=" " data-id="" ></option>
                  </datalist>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col">
                <label class="small gray" for="zvDek2">Zv. Dekani</label>
                <div>
                  <input list="zvDek2_list" name="zvDek2" id="zvDek2" class="inputText" />

                  //The third time 
                  <datalist id="zvDek2_list"> 
                    <option value=" " data-id="" ></option> 
                    <option value=" " data-id="" ></option> 
                  </datalist>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please show the entire template and indicate what part is empty when turned into HTML.  Templates themselves don't remove the data you pass in.  Also, please show the exact data that pass in to the template when rendering it.

Comment: The value of my options are empty the second time a want to display them in a datalist. When I press the input it displays the same number of options as the first time but with no value. My code is the same in both cases.

Comment: What do you mean "second time"?  Are there two occurrences of this data in the same template?  Or are you rendering the template more than once from scratch?  In my first comment, I asked you to add some additional info to your question - that info would help us answer.

Comment: I want to use the data i fetched from my database more than one time in the ejs file I'm rendering. Specifically in my case i make 4 queries and one of them is the data that is shown in my question. I want to use this data again in the same ejs file to show the list of people again. I will update my question to include the data passed in my file.

Comment: Referencing the data in your template is NOT destructive so the data will still be there for a 2nd use in the template unless you've done something wrong somewhere.  Please read my first comment.  I asked you to show more info - the whole template and the code that prepares the data and calls `res.render()`.  If you're not going to do that, then I will just move on and help others as there's nothing more for me to do here with the info you have in the question now.

Comment: I edited my question again. I hope I included everything that is needed.

Comment: OK, progress.  Now, can you show the generated HTML for this page (use View/Source from the browser to capture it)?

Comment: I included the html code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first one shows this syntax:

```
value="<%=element.emer_ped%> <%=element.mbiemer_ped%>"
```

Your second and third ones use a slightly different syntax:

```
value="<%element.emer_ped%> <%element.mbiemer_ped%>"
         ^                    ^
```

Notice the missing `=` where the `^` is pointing.  I don't personally know ejs syntax, but this looks like the one difference between the version that works and the one that doesn't.